# Manage variations with git?

Tags: git

I am building testcases from combinations of input data sets, rcfiles, etc.

```
TC    in1    in2    in3    rcf
--    ---    ---    ---    ---
01    v02    v07    ---    ---
02    v02    v11    v01    v03
...
```

Each of the input data sets (e.g.: in1) has variations, minor changes to a largely identical base. That is why I would like to treat them as variations (versions?) of the same data set and not as separate sets. Also, no 2 variations of any one data set can exist in a testcase.

I also foresee combinations of variations making up a new variation:

```
in1.v02 + in1.v03 = in1.v09.
```

I consider using git. Each data set could have its own git repository.
Variations could be realized through branches and a new combination through merging variation branches into a new branch...

I wonder if that is a sensible approach or if there is a better way (and tool) to manage file variations?

Comment: `Each data set could have its own git repository` ... no, this doesn't sound right.  More likely, you would have just one Git repo, and several branches in that repo.  But I'm not sure your use case is one for which Git is well suited.

Comment: I am not sure either and exactly the point why I ask, if this is sensible approach ... I am more than happy letting go of this idea for a better solution.

Comment: If you could keep things simple, and use branches somehow to do this within a single repository, that might be the path of least resistance.